# regular expression to find a particular code

Tags: regex, eclipse

Can someone help me with the regular expression to find and replace a particular code inside a large project in eclipse I am working on:

Eg: I want to select all code that contains following **"s != null"**

---

**Like:**

appUsers != null

groups != null

*and so on. . .*

**and replace with:**

CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(appUsers)

CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(groups)

---

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: (\S+?)\s*!=null replace by CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty($1)

Comment: sorry but that gives me: adUser.setCompleteName(newAdUserData[1]!=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\s+` if there is a space exists before and after to `!=`

**Regex:**

```
(\S+?s)\s+!=\s+null
```

Use `\w+` instead of \S+ if you don't want to capture any special characters.

```
(\w+?s)\s+!=\s+null
```

**Replacement string:**

```
CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty($1)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/7)

Comment: thanks for help bro, but it selects an extra opening brace: eg: (appUsers != null